# Display everything in one row css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to put 2 different div's in one row.
I tried creating a new div with display:inline/inline block both, but still they are still displayed in next line.
How can I use CSS o display everything in one row.

```
   <div id ="yourwrapper">

    <FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
    Box Name:
        <SELECT NAME="list1" ID="list1">
               <OPTION>CD1</OPTION>
         </SELECT>   
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="New" onClick="AddItem1()"/>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="Delete" onClick="DeleteItem1()"/>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="Copy" onClick="CopyItem1()"/>

  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try to float them? Show us your css.

Comment: Yes, I did Not working.

Comment: Can you show your html markup and css?

Comment: There are no DIVs in your example!?

Comment: Like this http://jsbin.com/ezeRIxIH/1/edit

Comment: It is working in this example but not mine. you have not used any div.

Comment: As SOO many people have mentioned, so us the code. I don't think we understand what you're trying to do. What is your CSS, put together a fiddle to display what you're trying to do. Why are the inputs showing up on a separate line? Are you using bootstrap (which sets inputs to block I believe), does the div have a max-width? We can't see these things, so can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
#yourwrapper {
  whitespace: no-wrap;
}
```

which will tell the css not to wrap the elements, and they'll go off the page.

Comment: I tried this CSS but its not working too. please check the edited code in myquestion. I want to display everything in one line

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#yourwrapper > div{
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: tried this but not working. Please check the edited code in the question. I want to display everything in one row.

Comment: I removed the div's and placed everything in one div now which is yourwrapper..

Comment: Show your complete code please

Comment: please check the question . If I want to display all this in one row. How can I achieve the same. there is one text then a dropdown and lastly 3 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use span rather than divs if you plan to use inline elements. To make elements align to each other use rather float:left (and then clear in the end) or display:inline-block.

Comment: Can you please show this with my example question.

Comment: This is your code, is already in one line. http://jsfiddle.net/artdias90/33MTz/

Comment: it is not in one row when I am adding this to my other code.